# T-SQL - ISNULL([Col1], index)??? - Is this possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In an Azure SQL Server is it possible to replace NULLS with an index value?

In other words, I have a column that usually contains a unique value. However, sometimes it does not have a number. I have a stored procedure that triggers when a user fills out a form, they assign an identifier (integer) to that form and then the stored procedure does a `MERGE` to update/insert the information into the dimension. If the number is already on the dimension, it updates that row, if not, it inserts. However, if the user does not include an identifier, I would like to assign one to that row.

How can something like this be done?

Comment: Depends on what columns used in join for merge statement

Comment: Use a temp table and set column value as identity or use a case statement to generate int value for null row

Comment: consider using a [**sequence**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) and get the next value within the sp if the user has not supplied a value - suitability obviously depends on the nature of your code. [**NEXT VALUE FOR**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) function can be used in stored procedures and triggers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions.  Here is the code for an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(col) over () as maxcol,
             row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as inc
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set col = maxcol + inc
    where col is null;
```

This does the updates on all rows.  Similar ideas could be used for a `merge`.